# Display empno,ename,sal,deptno,dname,location, Display highest paid employee of every department

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

How to display highest paid employee of every department WITH empno,ename,sal,deptno,dname,location....

```
select e.empno,e.ename, max(e.Sal),d.Deptno
  from DEPTNO d 
 inner join emp e
    on d.Deptno = e.DEPTNO 
 group by d.DEPTNO;
```

**Employee table:**
[image: Emp Table]

**Deptno table:**
[image: Deptno table]

Comment: what was the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `row_number()` analytic function makes this easy:

```
select e.empno,
       e.ename,
       e.sal,
       d.deptno,
       d.dname,
       d.loc
  from Deptno d
  join (select e.*,
               row_number() over (
                 partition by e.deptno
                     order by sal desc) as rn
          from Employee e) e
    on e.deptno = d.deptno
   and e.rn = 1
```

In this case, the `row_number()` function will return a value of `1` for the highest paid employee of every department, so that's why the join condition includes `e.rn = 1` to limit the results to those employees.

Comment: It means, select all columns from `e`. And `e` is just an alias for the `Employee` table, so it selects all Employee columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select empno,ename,deptno,sal from 
(
    select e.empno,e.ename,d.Deptno,sal,max(sal) over (partition by d.deptno order by null) max_sal from Employee e,Deptno d where e.deptno = d.deptno 
)where sal=max_sal
```

here max_sal return max salary with partition by department